# Toastr messages on conditional checkbox click angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, checkbox, angular6

**Introduction**:

I have a table with one column of the table consisting of only **checkboxes** as values.I have a button named **validate**. I have a **value** above the table.The **value** which I have assigned is 4. I need to show a toastr message if I enable more no of checkboxes than the number given above.

**Myissue**:

For example if the **number** above is 4,I can only check upto 4 checkboxes. If more than 4 **checkboxes** are checked.I need to show an toastr error message on validate button click.

**What I have tried(Optional read):**

**Html checkbox and validate button:**

```
<td>
    <input  type="checkbox" id="vehicle2" name="vehicle2"
      (change)="addCheckValue(i,list.isTicked)"
      [checked]="list.isTicked"
      [disabled]="list.isDisabled">
    </td>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success"
   (click)="error()"  ><span class="fa fa-plus"></span>Validate</button>
```

**TS:
Checkbox enable condition in TS:**

```
 addCheckValue(index, isChecked) {
    if (isChecked === undefined) {
      isChecked = true;
    }
    this.listes[index].isTicked = isChecked;
    console.log(this.listes);
    if (this.listes[index].isTicked === true) {
      this.counts = this.counts + 1;
    }
    if (this.listes[index].isTicked === false) {
      this.counts = this.counts - 1;
    }
  }
```

**Error message in TS:**

```
 error(){
 if(this.counts>this.a){

    this.toastr.error(
  `More cheeckboxes enabled.Total checkbox enabled is ${this.counts}`,
  "Total Error",
  {
    timeOut: 3000
  }

);}
   

 }
```

So this code didn't work because the **count** variable above counted the number of clicks on checkboxes(both checked and  unchecked) instead of counting how many **checkboxes** are checked. So if I have a value 4 and if I  check and uncheck a single checkbox 5 times it will show error which is not What I wanted. Kindly help me if u know.

**Stackblitzlink**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4vnwed?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

**Note:** Kindly let me know in the comments if my question is unclear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of handling checkbox state manually using `change` event you can use ngModel like below.

```
<input
    type="checkbox"
    id="vehicle2"
    name="vehicle2"
    [(ngModel)]="list.isTicked"
    [disabled]="list.isDisabled"
/>
```

This will maintain the status of list and then you in your button click you can get the selected checkboxs count like below and show the message.

```
validate(): void {
    var selectedItemsCount = this.listes.filter((x) => x.isTicked).length;
    if (selectedItemsCount > this.maxSelection) {
      this.toastr.error(
        `More cheeckboxes enabled.Total checkbox enabled is ${selectedItemsCount}`,
        "Total Error",
        {
          timeOut: 3000
        }
      );
    }
}
```

Here is the working codesandbox.

https://codesandbox.io/s/checkbox-ngmodel-p9282

**Edit 1:**
If you want to invoke the validate function on checkbox change then bind the ngModelChange event to checkbox and pass the validate function into it.

```
<input
    type="checkbox"
    id="vehicle2"
    name="vehicle2"
    [(ngModel)]="list.isTicked"
    (ngModelChange)="validate()"
    [disabled]="list.isDisabled"
/>
```

Comment: Good morning bro. Is there anyway to do it onchange? Like without clicking validate button. Because I have a bootstrap button. So it has data dismiss='modal which shows error message and also closes the the box. So it would be better if its on onchange

Comment: Just bind an ngModelChange event to that validate function. Check [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/checkbox-ngmodel-p9282?file=/src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: Bro can u pls check this question if ur free    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65195696/choose-multiple-files-with-a-delete-button-nearby-angular

Answer (score 0):

```js
 
 // Toggle checked flag.
 addCheckValue(index) {
    this.listes[index].isTicked = !this.listes[index].isTicked;
 }
 
 error() {
    const checkedCount = this.listes.filter(item => item.isTicked).length;
    if(checkedCount > this.a) {
       this.toastr.error(
          `More cheeckboxes enabled.Total checkbox enabled is ${this.counts}`,
          "Total Error",
          { timeOut: 3000 });
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way u can do that in onchange?