# Choose multiple files with a delete button nearby angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript, angular5

**Introduction**: I have a table where in a column it consists of an option to choose or upload files as an input to the table. I have written code in such a way that I can choose multiple files all at once.

**My problem**
What I want is that after I choose those multiple files(lets say 3 for an example), I need a x or a close symbol or a delete button near the filename. So that When I click that I could unchoose or unselect or delete the particular file alone. I am attaching a sample image of how I want.

And please tell me if there is any way to remove list values by index

[Sampleimageofthat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQQJv.png)

Kindly comment below if my question is unclear

**My html code:**

```
 <td>
    <ng-container>
     <input style="width:240%" type="file" id="file" multiple
         (change)="getFile($event)" >
      </ng-container>
</td>
```

**My ts code:**

```
myFiles:string [] = [];
getFile (e) {
for (var i = 0; i < e.target.files.length; i++) { 
  this.myFiles.push(e.target.files[i]);
}}
```

I have also attached my stackblitz below for your reference:

**Stackblitz**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4vnwed?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Hi you can attach a function and pass the image index to that function. In function you just simply splice that index from array.

Comment: I have tried that but didnt work. Can u please give me a sample stackblitz @Naseer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your html your forgot to add a **"let"** before **f** variable

```
<li *ngFor="let f of files">
```

In your app.components.ts file, try to use filter not map. this.files.map() isn't filtering out the elements. Console log the output to debug

```
  removeFile(i: number) {
   this.files = this.files.filter(x => x.index != i);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. I have done that but my problem is that when I choose files in a particular row the files get choose in all the rows. I want it to be selected in only one row    https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4vnwed?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: @angular Because you are just looping trough the Myfiles, you need to push new file changes to specific row list. In here `let list of listes;` so after you could reference it with for example `{{list.file.name}}`